# How to append another directory to an aliased `cd` command?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have aliased a long path in `.bashrc` file as

```
alias py="cd ~/Myprograms/Langs/workout/PythonScripts"
```

Now assume there is an another directory in PythonScripts say "basics"

How do I use the above alias without changing it, i.e, something like `py/basics`.

I tried this and it results in error

```
bash: py/basics: no such file or directory
```

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done with bash aliases, but you can use functions:

```
py () {
  cd ~/Myprograms/Langs/workout/PythonScripts/"$1"
}
```

`$1` is the first argument to the function. You can call it this:

```
py basics
```

Without any arguments, it would just `cd` to `~/Myprograms/Langs/workout/PythonScripts/`.

Comment: Come on muru, i need some spare points ;)

Comment: @heemayl bounties to be granted? I can help.

Comment: @heemayl That's a bit beyond what Stack Exchange will let me grant. :P

Comment: well then ....good for you ;)

Comment: Now if only this worked with bash-completion